# What is wrong with my code? It's for a locker puzzle

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def change(item):
    if (item == True):
        return False
    return True
def locker_puzzle(x):
    lockers = [False]*x
    num_students = 100
    num_lockers = 100
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        for j in range(j, x+1):
            if(j % i == 0):
                lockers[i-1] = change(lockers[i-1])
    count = 1
    for item in lockers:
        if (item == True):
            print(count)
        count = count+1
def main():
    locker_puzzle(100)
main()
```

output should be:

```
1
4
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

---

Solve the “locker puzzle.” A school has 100 students and 100 lockers. All lockers are closed on the first day of school. As the students enter, the first student (S1) opens every locker. Then the second student (S2) begins with the second locker (L2), and closes every other locker. Student S3 begins with the third locker (L3) and changes every third locker (closes it if it was open, and opens it if it was closed). Student S4 begins with locker L4 and changes every fourth locker. Student S5 begins with locker L5 and changes every fifth locker, and so on, until student S100 changes L100.

Comment: whats the output now?

Comment: `for j in range(j, ...)`?  Think about that.

Answer (score 2):

```
def locker_puzzle(n):
    lockers = [False] * n
    for s in range(n):
        for l in range(s, n, s + 1):
            lockers[l] = not lockers[l]
    return lockers
for i, locker in enumerate(locker_puzzle(100), 1):
    if locker:
        print(i)
```

This outputs:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but doesn’t explain what the OP’s error was.

Answer (score 1):

Using better names makes the error more apperent:

```
def locker_puzzle(num_lockers):
    lockers = [False]*num_lockers 

    for stud in range(1, num_lockers+1):
        for lock in range(stud, num_lockers+1,stud):  # you went wrong here
            lockers[lock-1] = not lockers[lock-1]  

    return lockers

def main():
    for i,v in enumerate(locker_puzzle(100)):
        if v:
            print(i+1)

main()
```

Output:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you went wrong here `for j in range(j, x+1):`
You should replace `j` with `i`.

A simpler solution would be this:

```
def locker_puzzle(x): 
    lockers = [False] * x
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        for j in range(i, x + 1, i):
            try:
                lockers[j-1] = not lockers[j-1]
            except IndexError as e:
                print(i, j)
                raise e
    for i, locker in enumerate(lockers):
        if locker:
            print(i+1)
```

This is how I would have solved it.